# Adding query parameter to archive page returns 404

Tags: wp-query, parameter

I've created a new post type called Creations.
On the creations archive `https://example.com/creations` I am showing a grid of creation posts.

If I add query parameter to the URL I get a 404, why is this happening? Even `https://example.com/creations?test=test` is returning 404 not found.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried adding a trailing slash - i.e. `https://example.com/creations/?test=test`? Sometimes the slash matters. If that doesn't work, I'd look into what particular parameters you're adding - some variable names aren't allowed. There is some function where you can add a query argument - I don't remember its name off the top of my head but you might need to explicitly declare your variable as a valid query argument for WordPress to understand it.

Comment: Hey @WebElaine and thank for the response. The trailing slash doesn't make a difference. I've just tried `?_test=1` i.e. added `_` before the parameter and it seems to work. the parameters I want to use are `topics` and `artists`, they are not in the list of saved saved wordpress terms. I assume the function you are referring to is ass_query_arg? I never understood how to use it :/